# What are the alternative race track fonts to Schilderwald?

Tags: font-recommendation

For some reason [Schilderwald](https://www.dafont.com/fr/schilderwald.font) doesn't work on my computer, and surprisingly I can't find ANY other font where characters look like a race track, road track etc.
I tried keyword search and image identification, there is nothing except vectors.

[image]

Comment: Ok it worked after conversion to OTF, but still I would appreciate other designs.

Comment: In dafont search for "road track". There are two others, but both are quite different from the font you are showing here.